# Problem calling my Angular application entry point with an ID - Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

So my problem is pretty basic but for some reason, I can't get it to work:

I want my application to be called with an ID. Something like:

`myapplication.com/1234` - where 1234 is an ID. Being provided an Id is a must for the start component.

To do this I created two routes:

```js
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'start/:id', component: StartComponent },
];
```

What I expected the behavior to be is that if someone navigates to `myapplication.com/1234` they will be redirected to start and the Id will be provided. However, I keep getting the error `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '1234'`. I do not want to use `queryParams` (?id=1234) so that is not an option. So my question is what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Shouldn't you redirect to `start/:id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `redirectTo` and define it in following way:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'start/:id', component: StartComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: StartComponent },
];
```

Both URLs will be resolved to `StartComponent` and you can handle `id` value there. You can also handle redirection in `StartComponent` if you need to.

Comment: I think you should "reorder" the path -put first `path:'start/id`- I'm not prety sure if a `path: ':id'` meets all routes -well really I'm not pretty sure you can indicate a router with an unique param-

Comment: @Eliseo true, changed.